# I Want To Make A Automated Key Presser For A Game

Tags: c#

hi i want to make a program that presses ctrl + v every 130 secs but it didnt worked for games (it worked for google, notepad etc.) i tried this code down below before

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TradeChatBot
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Start();
        }

        private void stop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Stop();
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SendKeys.Send("^{v}");
            SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is unclear: what would you expect "a game" to do? which game? does it even define an action on <Ctrl + V>? should it be a paste-from-clipboard action? define "does not work".

Comment: Checkout this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/how-to-simulate-mouse-and-keyboard-events-in-code

Comment: This greatly depends on the game you're trying to interface with. If the game is built using DirectX (good chance it is), it'll use the DirectInput system to process keyboard input from the device directly appose to the Windows event messaging system. The SendKeys method sends a key press through the windows system which is why it's working for some apps but not all.

Comment: @dlatikay warframe i want to do it for trade chat it just dont pastes the thing that i copied

Comment: perhaps it could process keystrokes and just does not understand <Ctrl+V>, or has a timing issue with the modifier. Does it work if you send it a single letter?

Comment: @dlatikay yes it does

Comment: Will your clicker work to click-click-click the down arrow on SO posts?  *That* would be useful!

Comment: then spell the clipboard content out letter by letter, and avoid the ctrl+v shortcut altogether.

Answer (score -1):

You can look into Clipboard class. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-Us/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard(v=vs.110).aspx

```
  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text= "SendKeys.Send(^{v}); ";
            Clipboard.SetText(textBox1.Text);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox2.Focus();
            SendKeys.Send("^{v}");
            SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
        }
```

Comment: actually i copied the sentence before so it has a value clipboard

Comment: @IstemihanMp I think you know, Timer1 should be enabled, or trigger in code.